# How to find substring of a string with whitespaces in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I want to check whether string contains particular sub string and using CONTAINS() for it.

But here problem is with space.

Ex- str1= "c not in(5,6)"

I want to check whether str contains NOT IN so I am using str.contains("not in")..

But problem is that here space between NOT and IN is not decided i.e. there can be 5 spaces also..

How to solve that I can find sub string like not in with any no of spaces in between...

Comment: Take a look at using regular expressions in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/): `"not\\s+in"`

```
    String s = "c not  in(5,6)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("not\\s+in").matcher(s);
    System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

**Explanation:** The `\\s+` means any kind of white space [tab is also acceptable], and must repeat at least one [any number >=1 will be accepted].

If you want only spaces, without tabs change your regex to `"not +in"`

Comment: This is working but still just for knowledge.
Is there any way by which we can reduce those spaces to 1?

Comment: @Sam: Again, using regex: `s.replaceAll("\\s+"," ")` will replace all white spaces to a single one.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) ([`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) to get a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to match your string.

The regexp should be `"not\\s+in"` ("not", followed by a number of space-characters, followed by "in"):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("not\\s+in").matcher("c not  in(5,6)");

    if (m.find())
        System.out.println("matches");
}
```

---

*Note that there is a String method called `matches(String regexp)`. You can use regular expression `".*not\\s+in.*"` to get the match but it's not really a good way to perform the pattern matching.*

Comment: This is working but still just for knowledge.
Is there any way by which we can reduce those spaces to 1?

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("not\\s+in", "not in")`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `String.matches()` method, which checks if the string matches a regular expression ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)).

In your case:

```
String str1 = "c not in(5,6)";
if (str1.matches(".*not\\s+in.*")) {
    // do something
    // the string contains "not in"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Case insensitive: `(?i)`

Considering newline as dot `.` too: `(?s)`

```
str1.matches("(?is).*not\\s+in.*")
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try following,

```
int result = str1.indexOf ( "not in" );

if ( result != -1 ) 
{
       // It contains "not in" 
}
else if ( result == -1 )
{
     // It does not contain "not in"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple spaces between "not" and "in".

Comment: Please read the question, OP indicates that there may be more than one space between "not" and "in"

Comment: There may be a variable number of spaces between "not" and "in", as stated in the question.

Answer (score -2):

In general you can just do this:

```
if (string.indexOf("substring") > -1)... //It's there
```

Comment: How does this handle the variable number of spaces between "not" and "in"?

Comment: You referenced the subject, but not to the question itself.